# How to find thermal diffusivity

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, experimental-technique

This is a question about  nondimensionalization in the heat equation
$$\rho c \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \kappa \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}~? $$

How could one devise a nondestructive experiment to find the thermal diffusivity i.e $\frac{\kappa}{\rho c}$?

Comment: In the current form it is not clear what your first question means... may be you could reformulate it. As of your second question, you could check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity#Measurement

Comment: I'm sorry. The question isn't clear. I didn't write correctly. I changed it

Comment: @Jama Hello and welcome to Physics.SE! Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far on how to do what you want?

Comment: Well I know I can write it as $u_t=D u_{tt}$ where D is the quantity I'm looking for. But that's not helping. Now I'm thinking that the units of D are $L^2 M T^-5$ and I should equate that to $[\rho]^a[c]^b[\kappa]^c$ and solve for $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise simply finding the individual properties $\rho, c, k$, as these can all be found via steady state experiments which are much easier to set up and would have less uncertainty.

As the equation implies, diffusivity as a property only really shows itself in transient cases, when time derivatives are non zero.

Comment: There are experimental techniques yielding directly the diffusivity. That's much simpler and precise than measuring these 3 quantities separately...

Comment: Can you give a little more detail into these techniques?